# Dialogflow Python API Required Parameter

Tags: python, dialogflow-es

I am trying to create a parameter that is required using the Python Dialogflow API v2. My current code is as follows:

```
                    parts.append(Intent.TrainingPhrase.Part(text=value,
                                                            alias=value,
                                                            entity_type='@' + value))
```

This works to create the parameter, but it is not required. The obvious first attempt was to add a required=True param, but that was not expected by the function call.

Looking at their docs (https://googleapis.dev/python/dialogflow/latest/gapic/v2/types.html) there does not seem to be any required/mandatory field.

I started to dig a little into their code, and found similar - there does not seem to be a required or mandatory field, except when creating the parameter?

https://github.com/googleapis/dialogflow-python-client-v2/blob/7bf592684b4d5df0cd1f66dd414efe2350d0461e/dialogflow_v2/proto/intent.proto

Answer (score 0):

Ah, got it. My mistake was that you can create parameters for an intent as I was doing above, and it will add the parameter, but not required. You can explicitly specify a parameter as well, which is what has the mandatory field. Like this:

```
    if len(parameters) > 0:
        for parameter in parameters:
            intent_parameter = Intent.Parameter(
                display_name=parameter.name,
                value=parameter.name,
                entity_type_display_name='@' + parameter.name,
                mandatory=True
            )

            intent.parameters.extend([intent_parameter])
```